# Can't read react state inside JSX in stack with NEXTJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, next.js

I'm having an issue with reading the state. Slider component nested inside [projects.js]. Since NextJS has a very convenient method for dynamic routings the main idea is to change most of the data inside a template component based on the current pathname.

The expected behavior for my code was to generate working path for images (look 'key' and 'src').

```
<motion.img
    ref={imageRef}
    className='absolute h-full md:rounded object-contain'
    key={images[src][imageIndex]}
    src={images[src][imageIndex]}
```

There're a couple of ways to do it:

1. Ask Next about the rout while client-side rendering and store it in the state.

```
    import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

    const router = useRouter();

    useEffect(() => {
        setSrc(router.query.project);
    }, [src]);
```

2. Use getInitialProps and store data there as first function fires on the server.

```
Carousel.getInitialProps = async query => {
    return {
        src: images[query.project]
    };
};
```

Preferably I would use the second option with initial props, but I can't with next JS. Functional of the slider doesn't allow to makу it because the code breaks when returning back to the previous page. NextJs just makes [projects.js] statically available on the client-side by default and restricts initial props.

So, when I'm using state it works fine, I can read from it in console.log

```
    console.log(src); ==== 'barva'
    // console.log(images.barva[0]); ====== ["/images/barva/barva-design.png", ...]
    // console.log(images[src][imageIndex]); Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Very strange behaivor since it reads my import with json file, it reads when assigned to the state, it shows pictures when I fill out path manualy without any dynamic variables, it even reads second part of the path [imageIndex] but it never reads state as [src] inside JSX.

Are there any better practices of how to import data to make component dynamic?
or How to fix this code??

repo to the project:
[gihub repo](https://github.com/kkdima/dima-k)